# checkbox check with database data

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have two mysql tables and looks like as follows. iam using PHP and MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject_category` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sid` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=191 ;

INSERT INTO `subject_category` (`id`, `sid`, `category`, `subject`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'GCE O/L', 'Sinhala'),
(2, 2, 'GCE O/L', 'Development Studies'),
(3, 3, 'GCE O/L', 'History'),
(4, 4, 'GCE O/L', 'Mathematics'),
(5, 5, 'GCE O/L', 'Citizan Education'),
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_subjects` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`usid` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;

INSERT INTO `user_subjects` (`id`, `uid`, `usid`) VALUES
(11, 142247454430186, 1),
(12, 142247454430186, 3),
(13, 142247454430186, 5)
```

actually what i need is, need to create check-box array using first table data. this part is already done. then i need to checked checkbox match with second table (subject_category.id=user_subjects.usid) for the particular user_subject.uid

**FINALLY i need 5 check boxes for data in first table and 3 of them have selected with to second table values**

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why do we have both an `id` and a `sid`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you start off the wrong way, you should do it in 1 step, not in two steps.

The mysql query you need is:

```
$query = 'SELECT sc.subject, CASE WHEN us.id IS NULL THEN "" ELSE "checked" AS checked
 FROM subject_category sc
  LEFT JOIN user_subjects us ON (us.usid = sc.id)';
```

With the result of this query you should be able to generate the checked and unchecked checkboxes at once.

*NOTE: I don't know which columns you need and if you needed sc.id or sc.sid in the join, but I think you can create the right query with this example.*

Next step PHP (with mysql_* function as the TS asks in comment, I know you should use PDO or mysqli):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="'.$line['checked'].'" name="subject" value="'. $line['subject'] .'" /> '.$line['subject'];
}
```

Comment: $q4=mysql_query("SELECT sc.subject, CASE WHEN us.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'checked' AS checked FROM subject_category sc  LEFT JOIN user_subjects us ON (us.usid = sc.id)"); 
 
 while($r4=mysql_fetch_array($q4))
{
 echo  $r4[0];
}

Comment: you shouldn't use mysql_* functions anymore, use PDO or mysqli instead, but I will update the solution

Comment: Please try the updated version, try not to post complete code in comments.... With the example you should figure it out yourself by now. Stackoverflow isn't the place to let someone else do your job!